# Start browser-sync using protractor

Tags: protractor, browser-sync

I have an e2e test setup for my non-angular application using Protractor. I want to hook up the test to run using Jenkins. However, I don't want a separate Jenkins task to start the browser-sync server. Can Protractor start browser-sync server and then run the test on it or do I need to use a task runner like Gulp?